# Wikipedia Mediawiki API get Pageid from URL

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I have a set of full urls like

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episkopi_Bay
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Lauro
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampedusa
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himera
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lago_Cecita
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspromonte
```

I want to find ***wikipedia pageids*** for these URLS. I have used the Mediawiki API before but I cant figure out how I may do this.

I have tried extracting the page title from the URLs by taking a substring of lastindexof("/") and the last character and then querying the API to get pageid.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episkopi_Bay --> Episkopi_Bay
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Lauro --> Monte_Lauro
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampedusa -- > Lampedusa
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himera --> Himera
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lago_Cecita --> Lago_Cecita
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspromonte --> Aspromonte
```

But the problem is that some of my links might be redirects and hence the substring might not always be the title of the page.

**TL;DR : How can I find the pageid of a wikipedia page from a URL ?**

Answer (score 7):

I’m not sure if what you call "page id" is the identification number of the page (e.g. 15580374 for English Wikipedia’s Main Page -- found on "Page information" in the toobox in left column) or the normalised title of a page with redirects resolved. The answer below will answer both.

You can use the API action=query, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page where you will find minimal information, whose the page id (number).

You can also want to manage more complex cases: title normalisation and/or redirects. Title normalisation (initial capital, underscores changed to spaces, various unicode normalisations iirc, etc.) is included out-of-the box. For redirects, you have to ask specifically by adding "&redirects" to the URL (note that double redirects (=redirect of a redirect) won’t work, but the should not be out there). Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=main_page&redirects

If you need more information, you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Binfo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about both of these methods but none help my cause. In both of your answers I need a page_title to work with. I dont have a page_title, I only have the URL. That is where the problem lies. URLs cant be translated to page_titles by substring. Also page_titles can contain non-english UTF8 encoded text. Which wont necessarily be there in URL and shows up as a bunch of transliterated text.

Comment: Ok. So you have to first extract the substring as you said, then call the API to normalise the title and resolve the redirects (even with %-encoded titles like https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A7), and in the case of non-latin characters you have to encode the returned string to UTF8 (e.g. for the French word "Café" the API returns "title": "Caf\u00e9", where "é" is Unicode U+E9).

Answer (score 5):

You can add &indexpageids to your query.

For example

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Main%20Pages&indexpageids

or if you are looking for a summary at the same time, here's a more comprehensive example link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=barberton%20daisy&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&indexpageids

Then if you parse the JSON you will see a property named pageids under query

Answer (score 2):

If you have only the URL, and don't know anything about the wiki, you cannot assume that the part after the last `/` is the page title, as MediaWiki pages names [may contain](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_title) `/`. Instead, you will have to start by querying the siteinfo API, like this:

```
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Siteinfo
```

In the reply, `query.general.server` and `query.general.articlepath` combined will give you the url structure, and `query.general.script` will give you the [scriptpath](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgScriptPath). Depending on where your url's come from, you will need them booth, to account for the default form `//mywiki/scriptpath/index.php?title=Namespace:Foo/Bar`, and the short url form `//mywiki/articlepath/Namespace:Foo/Bar`, for an article named `Foo/Bar`.

To make matters worse, the slash in the “article name” can be either part of the name, or a delimiter for a subpage, depending on the settings of that namespace!

If you know the url syntax of the wikis at hand, @Seb35 already answered all your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Will just paste some working code here for others coming across this page in google. I couldn't find a way to do this through the api, this code snippet goes to the actual page and extracts the page_id from there. Uses beautifulsoup and regex to do it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import re

# Here list_of_urls is the list of urls 
     #['http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episkopi_Bay', etc.]

list_page_ids = []

for url in list_of_urls:        
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    script_content = soup.select_one("head > script:nth-of-type(1)").decode_contents()
    page_id = re.search(r".*wgArticleId..([0-9]+).*",script_content).group(1)
    list_page_ids.append[page_id]
    time.sleep(3)

print(list_page_ids)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only answer that actually addresses the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

An API call with `action=query` gives you the `pageid` of an article :

```
https://xx.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=searched_title
```

Gives a JSON like :

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "xxxx": {
                "pageid": xxxx,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "searched_title"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of this answer addresses the fact that only the url is available?

Comment: I never use this API again. This answer is probably outdated.